# MEF, Prism and new view instance on navigation

Tags: wpf, mef, prism-6

The code below worked on shared instance of the view.   Now what I'm trying to achieve is each time I navigate to `ViewB` I want a new instance of the view and its backing view model.  I have tried various combinations of the below but they all seem to ultimately end with the `RequestNavigate` failing silently the second time I try to navigate to ViewB...

I have also tried setting `IsNaviagtionTarget` to false after the view has been navigated to once.

**Bootstrapper:**

```
public void Initialize()
{
    _regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNameConstants.MainRegion, typeof(ViewA));
    _regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNameConstants.MainRegion, typeof(ViewB));
}
```

**ViewB (class):**

```
[RegionMemberLifetime(KeepAlive = false)]
[Export]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
internal partial class ViewB
{
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public ViewB(ViewBViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = viewModel;
    }
}
```

**ViewBViewModel:**

```
[Export(typeof(ViewBViewModel))]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
internal class ViewBViewModel : BindableBase, INavigationAware
{
    public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {
    }

    public bool IsNavigationTarget(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {
    }
}
```

ViewA simply has a button with a command that calls:

**ViewA Navigation command:**

```
public override void Execute(object parameter)
{
    _regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNameConstants.MainRegion, new Uri(nameof(ViewB), UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't register `typeof(ViewB)` with the region manager in the bootstrapper:

```
public void Initialize()
{
    _regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNameConstants.MainRegion, typeof(ViewA));
}
```

And since you are navigating to the Uri of `nameof(ViewB)`, you should also export the view with a contract name of `nameof(ViewB)`:

```
[Export(nameof(ViewB))]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
[RegionMemberLifetime(KeepAlive = false)]
internal partial class ViewB
{
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public ViewB(ViewBViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = viewModel;
    }
}
```

Then you should get a new instance of ViewB each time you navigate to it using:

```
_regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNameConstants.MainRegion, new Uri(nameof(ViewB), UriKind.Relative));
```

Comment: The magic was in the nameof(ViewB), that worked without the additional register I used in my answer.  Good call.